# How can I verify an XFS dump backup

Tags: backup, xfs

I recently had a hard drive crash. Now I'm setting up incremental backups using XFS' dump tool.

The setup I have is to make the dumps into files (rather than to a block device), my plan is to do a l0 dump every month or two, and l1 dumps every week, and l2 every day.

So the commands I'm running are things like:

```
 sudo xfsdump -f backups  -l0 -p5 -L `date +%y-%m-%d` -M 'backup' /
 sudo xfsdump -f `date +%y-%m-%d-l1` -l1 -p5 -L `date +%y-%m-%d-l1` -M 'backup' /
```

Now, my main question is: **what's the best way for me to verify the backups work**
and additionally, **how can I delete the entries in the inventory for backups in files that I deleted**, because while I was messing around with the backup tool, I created a few backups in files, then deleted the files.

Comment: The *only* way to verify that your backups are working is to restore from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to restore a single file from it and see what happens.  If it works, then one can be pretty sure that the backup is ok.  This is not 100% mind you.

The only way to verify that would be to do a FULL restore and then (if possible) compare the files you restored to the files you backed up.....difficult on a changing filesystem.

Comment: This did end up working when some files got derped in a crash, so I guess it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to do **not** use xfsbackup for regular backups. Backup tools that stuff anything inside a single file are often vulnerable to a single fatal error, where a problem in the base file or in the incremental steps give you an useless backup.

Rsync / Rsnapshot are way better tools for this kind of work, especially considering that they give you a "live" snapshot directory where inconsistencies will be limited to some file at most, but they can't bring down the entire backup. Moreover, using hard links, you can have an incremental backup without the inconveniences associated to it.

Comment: I've been doing backup levels, so every once in a while I'll do a full dump.

But I'd never heard of rsnapshot, it looks like a better way to do this.

Comment: xfsbackup can backup quotas, xattrs and hard links properly, not to mention being tolerant of errors in backup files and can generate multi-level backups at will.  Using rsnapshot/rsync is great for some things, but it is not a full replacement for what xfsbackup and other actual backup programs do.

Answer (score -3):

You can delete old entries in the inventory with tool xfsinvutil either interactively or from script.
xfsinvutil -F -s SessionID - this will remove entry with particular SessionID
xfsinvutil -F -M mount_point mm/dd/yyyy - prunes dump sessions identified by the given mount point which were created prior to the specified date
xfsinvutil -F -u UUID mm/dd/yyyy - similar but with UUID
xfsinvutil -i - interactive mode
To get SessionID, UUID etc. run xfsdump -I | more
For more details see man page: man xfsinvutil, man xfsdump.
xfsinvutil is in xfsdump.rpm and is in base repository in CentOS7.

Comment: This need a better explanation. As it stand, this is not sufficient as an answer.